# Change naming strategy in Aqueduct ORM

Tags: dart, orm, aqueduct

Is it possible to setup Aqueduct ORM to use underscored names for database columns (so if I have field "someField" in model class it will be stored as "some_field" in the database)? Or may be it is at least possible to override column name by some annotation? I have legacy database schema with underscored names and I cannot change it).

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet, as of May 2020. Please upvote [the associated Github issue](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/693).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question, "This is not supported yet", along with a link to the Github issue for the feature request.